# Beta Weights Equivalent?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, importance

I know that the beta weight tells you the relative importance of a predictor (IV) in predicting the criterion (DV).

However, is it true that beta weights can not be compared across different samples? (i.e. if I run two different regressions, both with the same independent variables, but different dependent variables, I still cannot compare the beta weights for the same IV across the two samples)?

If one cannot compare beta weights across samples, is there a method to do so? I'm really wanting to know if the relative importance of a predictor (IV) stays constant, grows, or diminishes over time.

Thanks!